# Add custom image page property in CQ5

Tags: aem

Every page in CQ5 can have an image attached to it in page properties.  I need to add my own image property to be used in a component.

I am able to add small things as a check box using [this link](https://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/CQ5PageProps.html) but when I add a new image tab in the page properties, even the existing image stops working.
Even if I can add another image dialog in the page, I am unable to fetch the new image.  This is the new image dialog I've added. (see attachment)

I just want to use the image in the carousel [maybe fetch it using :

```
Resource r = page.getContentResource("image1");
```

[image: JCR-structure-of-image-dialog]

Can someone please help me on this ? What properties do I at least need to make it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an `xtype` of `smartimage` (or a version of this, e.g. `html5smartimage`).

Here's some sample code that will add two images in a dialog — **imageOne** and **imageTwo**. You need to make sure that the properties of your new image don't conflict with the existing one — namely the `fileNameParameter`, `fileReferenceParameter`, `name` and the `name` of the child node `resType` should be unique in the example below.

```
<items jcr:primaryType="cq:TabPanel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <imageOnePanel
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Image One Panel">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <imageOne
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        border="true"
                        ddGroups="[media]"
                        fileNameParameter="./imageOne/fileName"
                        fileReferenceParameter="./imageOneFileReference"
                        height="300"
                        hideLabel="true"
                        name="./imageOne/file"
                        xtype="html5smartimage">
                    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                        <resType
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                ignoreData="{Boolean}true"
                                name="./imageOne/sling:resourceType"
                                value="foundation/components/image"
                                xtype="hidden"/>
                    </items>
                </imageOne>
            </items>
        </imageOnePanel>
        <imageTwoPanel
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Image Two Panel">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <imageTwo
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        border="true"
                        ddGroups="[media]"
                        fileNameParameter="./imageTwo/fileName"
                        fileReferenceParameter="./imageTwoFileReference"
                        height="300"
                        hideLabel="true"
                        name="./imageTwo/file"
                        xtype="html5smartimage">
                    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                        <resType
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                ignoreData="{Boolean}true"
                                name="./imageTwo/sling:resourceType"
                                value="foundation/components/image"
                                xtype="hidden"/>
                    </items>
                </imageTwo>
            </items>
        </imageTwoPanel>
    </items>
</items>
```

Reusing code from the dialog & not giving unique properties might have caused you issues with adding a second image, though I'm not 100% from the error you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks so much.. I can see 2 images saved in CRX. But I need only 1 of them in my carousel. I use "Resource r = page.getContentResource("imageTwo");" but I still get the default image i.e the one I' get if I use page.getContentResource("image"); ..  any suggestions on this one ?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure — you should have nothing on the page that's called `image` if you're using the above as is, or do you still have the default image in the dialog too? If you print out `${properties.imageOneFileReference}` and `${properties.imageTwoFileReference}`, do you get what's expected? It's hard to tell for sure what's going on without seeing your JCR structure.

Comment: Thanks for your interest.. I have updated the question with the JCR properties screenshot. And yes, I am also using the default image dialog present in the "page" component.  Please suggest where I might've gone wrong.

Comment: By the looks of it, you have a mixture of properties for "image" and "image1" on the one node (e.g. `cropParameter` refers to `image`, but `fileNameParameter` refers to `image1`.) — can't really say where you've gone wrong without seeing the dialog you're using & the overall node structure, rather than just the properties. I'd suggest trialling the dialog snippet above on a fresh template type that doesn't already contain an image & seeing if that works.